# US Patent LaTeX Template Drawing scaling

Tags: floats, templates, scaling, tikz-graphdrawing

I found this LaTeX template online on this link https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/other/us-patent

However, I could not find any way to add my TikZ diagrams into the drawing section. Also, I am not sure how to scale my figures that are in `.jpg` or `.png`. Please someone help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

## How to add tikz diagrams

- Put your tikz diagram (`\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`) into a file named e.g. `TikzDrawing.tex`. As an example, put the line

  ```
  \tikz\node[draw]{A};
  ```

  into this file. (This will draw a box with an A in it).
- Add the following lines at the beginning of the document, near `\begin{document}`. In the ShareLaTeX template, you can add the lines to the file `Drawings.tex` that is included by the main document.

  ```
  \figureDefinition{TikzDrawing}
  \figureExtension{tex}
  \figureDescription{is an example drawing created with Tikz}
  ```
- In the text of the patent, refer to the figure using

  ```
  \referencePatentFigure{TikzDrawing}
  ```

Then the reference is typeset as [image] and the TikZ picture appears in the appendix as

[image]

## How to scale pdf/png/jpg figures

You have to add the following definitions to your preamble (i.e., between `\documentclass[...]{...}` and `\begin{document}`).

```
\documentclass[english]{uspatent}
\makeatletter
\def\figureOptions#1{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname anofigoptions \the\@annotationfigurenumber\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\def\csname anofigoptions \the\@annotationfigurenumber\endcsname{#1}
\else
\message{error while assigning option(s) ``#1'' to annotation figure number
``\the\@annotationfigurenumber'' - it was already defined as
``\annotationListFigureOptions{\the\@annotationfigurenumber}''.}\fi}
\def\annotationListFigureOptions#1{\csname anofigoptions #1\endcsname}
\def\showfigureincgraphics#1#2#3{%
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\edef\options{\annotationListFigureOptions{\csname fignum#1 \endcsname}}%
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\options]{#1.#2}\par
\figureReference{#1}~~#3 \par
\end{figure}
}
\expandafter\let\csname showfigure unk\endcsname\showfigureincgraphics
\expandafter\let\csname showfigure pdf\endcsname\showfigureincgraphics
\makeatother
\begin{document}
```

Now you can load all images with an extension acceptable to `\includegraphics` by adding lines like the following ones to `Drawings.tex` (or whereever you have your image definitions).

```
\figureDefinition{example-image}
\figureExtension{jpg}
\figureDescription{is an example jpg image with options}
\figureOptions{scale=0.5}

\figureDefinition{example-image-a}
\figureExtension{png}
\figureDescription{is an example png image with options}
\figureOptions{scale=0.5}

\figureDefinition{example-image-b}
\figureExtension{pdf}
\figureDescription{is an example pdf image with options}
\figureOptions{scale=0.5}
```

If we add these lines to the example document that comes with the template, we get the following output; see figures 3, 4, and 5.

[image]

[image][image]